# Keep only columns with matching column names

Tags: r, dataframe, bioconductor

I want to retain the column names in all three dataframes `met.kirp.450`, `met.kirc.450`, and `met.kich.450` from SummarizedExperiment data type, before merging column-wise.

First, I find the matching columns `match.col` before submitting the data frames with these matching columns. Then, I performed `SummarizedExperiment::cbind`.

```
dflist <- list(met.kirp.450, met.kirc.450, met.kich.450)
match.col <- Reduce(function(x, y){intersect(x, names(y))}, dflist, init = names(dflist[[1]]))
met.kirp.450 <- met.kirp.450[match.col,]
met.kirc.450 <- met.kirc.450[match.col,]
met.kich.450 <- met.kich.450[match.col,]

met.kipan <- SummarizedExperiment::cbind(met.kirp.450, met.kirc.450, met.kich.450)
```

Traceback:

```
Error in .aggregate_and_align_all_colnames(all_colnames, strict.colnames = strict.colnames) : 
  the DFrame objects to combine must have the same column names
```

I'm unable to print the dput because even a minimal `dput(met.kirp.450[1,1])` is too long.

Data:

```
library(TCGAbiolinks)

query.met.kirp <- GDCquery(
  project = "TCGA-KIRP", 
  legacy = TRUE,
  data.category = "DNA methylation",
  platform = "Illumina Human Methylation 450", 
)
GDCdownload(query.met.kirp)

query.met.kirc <- GDCquery(
  project = "TCGA-KIRC", 
  legacy = TRUE,
  data.category = "DNA methylation",
  platform = "Illumina Human Methylation 450", 
)
GDCdownload(query.met.kirc)

query.met.kich <- GDCquery(
  project = "TCGA-KICH", 
  legacy = TRUE,
  data.category = "DNA methylation",
  platform = "Illumina Human Methylation 450", 
)
GDCdownload(query.met.kich)

met.kirp.450 <- GDCprepare(
  query = query.met.kirp,
  save = TRUE, 
  save.filename = "gbmDNAmet450k.rda",
  summarizedExperiment = TRUE
)

met.kirc.450 <- GDCprepare(
  query = query.met.kirc,
  save = TRUE, 
  save.filename = "gbmDNAmet450k.rda",
  summarizedExperiment = TRUE
)

met.kich.450 <- GDCprepare(
  query = query.met.kich,
  save = TRUE, 
  save.filename = "gbmDNAmet450k.rda",
  summarizedExperiment = TRUE
)
```

Comment: @RicVillalba That returned `RangedSummarizedExperiment>[,j] index out of bounds:` error

Comment: What do you want your final output to look like? Merged by similar columns or all columns from all three data frames present? Even if you can do `dput` you could at least provide mock example data

Comment: I'll be adding a mock data.

Reference:
https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/workflows/vignettes/TCGAWorkflow/inst/doc/TCGAWorkflow.html#Epigenetic_analysis

Comment: Guess you put the column names in the row place. Shouldn't it be `met.kirp.450[ , match.col ]` etc. instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the objects are in SummarizedExperiment format, the column names can be retrieved from `y@colData@rownames`, where `colData` means column data.

```
match.cols <- Reduce(function(x, y){intersect(x, y@colData@rownames)}, dflist, init = colnames(dflist[[1]]))

met.kirp.450.new <- met.kirp.450[,match.cols]
met.kirc.450.new <- met.kirc.450[,match.cols]
met.kich.450.new <- met.kich.450[,match.cols]

met.kipan <- SummarizedExperiment::cbind(met.kirp.450.new, met.kirc.450.new, met.kich.450.new)
```